# Creating downloads for a 'page' content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cck

I need each 'page' node to have a number of downloads attached to it. So if I have a page called 'about me', the downloads could be:

- cv.pdf
- tax_return_2010.pdf
- what_I_like.pdf

There may be up to 10 downloads attached to a node.

I need the ability to add a title too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The default Drupal "File Attachment" functionality will do this for you. You can enable it in the admin area under Content -> Content Type -> (Your Content Type). Go to the "Workflow Settings" and enable "Attachments". Then you will see the "File Attachment" dialogue on all nodes of that type. You can upload files to it and choose to "List" them at the bottom of the node. There's even a box to type in a description/title for each file you upload.